# How to hide the collapse menu default in kibana visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using kibana 6.4 to visulaize the data.

In dashboard page how to hide the side menu by default.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Use 'Full Screen' option on top to view the dashboard in full screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable elasticsearch/kibana security first:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/configuring-security.html

and then create a user with the role **kibana_dashboard_only_user**. Here how to do it:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-dashboard-only-mode